# Summernote and FPDF

Tags: wysiwyg, fpdf, summernote

I am using this lovely [Summenote WISWYG editor](https://summernote.org/)

How can I use this in an PDF generated with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

When I use this example FPDF outputs:

```
<p><b>Testnotie</b></p><ol><li>Optie A<br></li><li>Optie B</li><li>Optie C</li></ol><p><br></p><p style="text-align:
center; "><span style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);">Belangrijk</span></p>
```

[image]

Comment: Can't help you with FPDF. But have built many Summernote applications that sit above our @cloudformatter application that can PDF the content of the editor.

Comment: I have seen @cloudformatter this week, but I was unable to visit te download page to take an look, some other pages are now down as well?

Comment: If you have an issue using @cloudformatter, contact us directly through the site or on the css-to-pdf tag in a separate question. The site has had no issues that I see, 22,000 formatting requests for 62,000 pages in the past several days.